# What is the easiest way to use HAML and SASS in no ruby project?

Tags: ruby, npm, rubygems, haml

I need to use haml with sass in order to create templates. I don't want to use rails. My main issue is haml partials including.

Here is my current project structure:

- build
- source
  -- scss
  -- js
  -- views
  --- pages
  ---- home.haml
  -- index.haml

I've tried to include home.haml as a partial in index.haml in different ways but no result. What should I install additionally (some gems or anything else) for my project in order to use HAML partials smoothly? Was looking how to fix it during 3 hours already and didn't find exact answer.

Comment: How are you serving our pages? Static web server? Then you need to compile haml to html in your build process. It can be done with the ruby haml gem but there probably are options for npm out there also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, i also take advantage of html preprocessor language to have a "backend build advantage", to compose the html make it more dynamic.

there's some tools that might help you like prepros or koala, i suggest prepros, it can compile haml to html and other preprocessors language.

contact me and i can explain more.

Answer (score -2):

If you are just building a static project, you have lots of options. I'd check out a Node.js-based build tool like [gulpjs.com](http://gulpjs.com/) or static site framework like [jekyllrb.com](http://jekyllrb.com/)